# Broken register after setting up SSL

Tags: php, sql

Basically I set up a self signed SSL certificate and all of a sudden my register forum stopped working, it almost feels as if it goes into a redirect loop but it doesn't, the way my register works is that you need to verify you account by email. When you click the register, the page doesn't load for a couple of minutes and then it eventually gives you the notification that the verification sent but it doesn't send to your email address. Also before I set up the self signed SSL it did work, I believe it's because SSL doesn't see my register.php forum as secure therefor it doesn't send it because it's uncrypted, if there is a bypass or a way to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
define('DIRECT', TRUE);
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
/* Registration process, inserts user info into the database 
   and sends account confirmation email message
 */

// Set session variables to be used on activate.php page
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['firstname'];

// Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
$username = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = getRealIpAddr();
$dateTime = date('Y/m/d G:i:s');
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$uncryptpass = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

// Check if user with that email already exists
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

// We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'An account with ' .$email. ' already exists!';
    header("location: /login/index.php");

}
else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

    // active is 0 by DEFAULT (no need to include it here)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, uncryptpass, password, hash, ip, date) " 
            . "VALUES ('$username','$email','$uncryptpass','$password', '$hash', '$ip', '$dateTime')";

    // Add user to the database
    if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

        $_SESSION['active'] = 0; //0 until user activates their account with verify.php
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // So we know the user has logged in
        $_SESSION['message'] =

                 "Confirmation link has been sent to $email, please verify
                 your account by clicking on the link in the message!";

        // Send registration confirmation link (verify.php)
        $to      = $email;
        $subject = 'Account Verification';
        $message_body = '
        '.$username.',

        ***DO NOT RESPOND BACK TO THIS EMAIL***

        https://example.com/login/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash;  

        mail( $to, $subject, $message_body );

        header("location: activate.php"); 

    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
        header("location: /login/index.php");
    }

}
```

Comment: Use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) -- there's virtually no reason to use a self-signed cert nowadays.

Comment: I can't see anything in this code that'd care about SSL vs. non-SSL.

Comment: Ok I actually just tested something, I took out the line that sent out the mail and it instantly loaded, so in that case is there an alternative method in sending a secure encrypted email in php with the SSL certificate?

Comment: Never store the plain text password in your database.

Comment: Are you able to send an email from an other script? If not, check your error logs to find related errors

Comment: Your verification hash has only 1000 possible values. Use `random_bytes()` instead.

Comment: Don't use the escape_string methods to prevent SQL injection, they are not sufficient. Use prepared statements with bound parameters instead.